# Angular.js custom directive and d3.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js, directive

Its not that difficult to get an `angular.js` directive combined with d3 to work(thanks to stackoverflow). But i cant get those arrows to work. The code is taken from an example of M.Bostock. 
[(Original Example)](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292)
I just wanted to put it in a directive and failed. It renders fine when i inspect the DOM i can see the arrows but they wont show up. Does anyone have a clue ?

Directive

```
angular.module('test').directive('myNodes', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // http://blog.thomsonreuters.com/index.php/mobile-patent-suits-graphic-of-the-day/
        var links = [
          {source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "licensing"},
          {source: "Microsoft", target: "HTC", type: "licensing"},
          {source: "Samsung", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
          {source: "Motorola", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
          {source: "Nokia", target: "Apple", type: "resolved"},
          {source: "HTC", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
          {source: "Kodak", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
          {source: "Microsoft", target: "Barnes & Noble", type: "suit"},
          {source: "Microsoft", target: "Foxconn", type: "suit"},
          {source: "Oracle", target: "Google", type: "suit"},
          {source: "Apple", target: "HTC", type: "suit"},
          {source: "Microsoft", target: "Inventec", type: "suit"},
          {source: "Samsung", target: "Kodak", type: "resolved"},
          {source: "LG", target: "Kodak", type: "resolved"},
          {source: "RIM", target: "Kodak", type: "suit"},
          {source: "Sony", target: "LG", type: "suit"},
          {source: "Kodak", target: "LG", type: "resolved"},
          {source: "Apple", target: "Nokia", type: "resolved"},
          {source: "Qualcomm", target: "Nokia", type: "resolved"},
          {source: "Apple", target: "Motorola", type: "suit"},
          {source: "Microsoft", target: "Motorola", type: "suit"},
          {source: "Motorola", target: "Microsoft", type: "suit"},
          {source: "Huawei", target: "ZTE", type: "suit"},
          {source: "Ericsson", target: "ZTE", type: "suit"},
          {source: "Kodak", target: "Samsung", type: "resolved"},
          {source: "Apple", target: "Samsung", type: "suit"},
          {source: "Kodak", target: "RIM", type: "suit"},
          {source: "Nokia", target: "Qualcomm", type: "suit"}
        ];
        var nodes = {};
        // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
        links.forEach(function(link) {
          link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
          link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
        });
        var width = 960,
            height = 500;
        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
            .links(links)
            .size([width, height])
            .linkDistance(60)
            .charge(-300)
            .on("tick", tick)
            .start();

        var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);
        // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
        svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
            .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
          .enter().append("marker")
            .attr("ng-attr-id", function(d) { return d; })
            .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
            .attr("refX", 15)
            .attr("refY", -1.5)
            .attr("stroke", "green")
            .attr("stroke-width", "2")
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .attr("markerWidth", 6)
            .attr("markerHeight", 6)
            .attr("orient", "auto")
          .append("path")
            .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

            element.removeAttr("my-nodes");
            $compile(element)(scope);

            // markerHeight = "3" stroke = "green" stroke-width = "2" fill = "none"

        var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
            .data(force.links())
          .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
            .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

             element.removeAttr("my-nodes");
            $compile(element)(scope);
        var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
            .data(force.nodes())
          .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("r", 6)
            .call(force.drag);

             element.removeAttr("my-nodes");
            $compile(element)(scope);

        var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
            .data(force.nodes())
          .enter().append("text")
            .attr("x", 8)
            .attr("y", ".31em")
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
            element.removeAttr("my-nodes");
            $compile(element)(scope);

        // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
        function tick() {
          path.attr("d", linkArc);
          circle.attr("transform", transform);
          text.attr("transform", transform);
           //element.removeAttr("my-nodes");
           // $compile(element)(scope);
        }

        function linkArc(d) {
          var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
              dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
              dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
          return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
        }

        function transform(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        }
            }
        };
    }]);
```

HTML

```
<div my-nodes></div>
```

[Plunker Illustrating the Problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nof5oL5JgOpu3cziQElx?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I created a plnkr based on what you provided and it works OK - are your references to AngularJS and D3 OK?

Edit:
[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ndbKdH6wiSxyp2ipOXSH?p=info) demo

```
<head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.21"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.6/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div my-nodes></div>
</body>
```

Comment: First off all...Thanks for your quick responses. I'm aware of the styling issues simply didnt provide any css. The graph also works fine on my system. There is just this "one" big issue the graph wont render the arrows as seen in the Original by Bostock. The problem must be somehow related to the angular.js directive lifecycle ?

Comment: @MunichAngularMan why do you think there is an issue with directive lifecycles, do you go to his Plnkr?  Unless you are using a crappy browser like IE it looks great.

Comment: I'm using chrome. Take a look at the new Plunkr on my first post and tell me you are seeing those damn arrows

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the "marker-end" attribute on the path for the lines.  In my plnkr example, the URL is different to that on Bostock's example.

Comment: Fixed, see: http://plnkr.co/edit/mYRoPVDP95vFw7YkHrAG

The lines and line ends were styled with CSS, which gives you the arrows.

Comment: Great blackn1ght thanks for your help...i'm looking at this for two long. So what exactly is the problem missing CSS ?

Comment: You know what, I think there is actually a change in the directive link code, as when I added the CSS it made the lines thin, however there were no arrow heads.  I copied and pasted the link function from his example (I'd changed mine so wanted it as per the original) and it fixed it.

I just looked at your recent plnkr and I can see you have the thin lines but no arrow heads, so it may be worth updating the directive link function and comparing to see what's different.

Comment: He's just removed the angular directive in the marker by this attr("id", function(d) { return d; }). I assume that's not what you wanted.

Comment: I had that "ng-attribute" prefix left by accident. With deleting that attribute my plnkr works fine. Thanks for your support ! I think the problem was more style related than i thought.

Comment: But whenever i try to use it in a directive inside of DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack frame it renders again everything except the arrows at the end of the links.